# How do I find other players on little big planet?

Tags: little-big-planet

How do I know what levels other players are in?

Comment: When having selected or hovering over a level it should say how many people are playing it right now. But I think the game should be dead by now, so you won’t find any players

Comment: Bass is right, unless if you're playing LBP3 then there might be some people. The first 2 are probably almost totally dead.

Answer (score 1):

[As of September 21st 2021](https://twitter.com/LittleBigPlanet/status/1437415883752845318), the servers for LittleBigPlanet 1 have been shut down. Unfortunately, this means it is no longer possible to play LBP1 online with other players.

The only alternative way of playing LBP1 levels online with other players would be via the PS4 version of LittleBigPlanet 3.

Answer (score 0):

To the right of the community option you can search for levels using different filters. If your looking for your friends levels go to the left planet in your pod and select your friends. When you click on a friend it will load any levels they have on the middle planet.